# how to tell to modelsim to exit when PSL assertion triggers?

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

I'm using modelsim (Mentor, v104) to make VHDL simulations. I use embedded PSL assertions of e.g. this style

```
-- psl assert always (
-- {ADCClockxQ.ClkxE} |-> {AmplitudeDataxQ.DxE})
-- abort not ADCClockxQ.ValidxS
-- report "Amplitude data enable not correctly aligned with turn clock";
```

Problem is, that when the assertion fails, modelsim does not stop and exit the simulation even when I tell him to do so by issuing following command:

`assertion fail -action exit`

The simulation just continues.

This makes a trouble e.g. when using python VUnit, which does not recognize this as a failure condition. So at the end, the VUnit reports that the testbench passed OK, while it is not true, because it ignores the embedded PSL asserts.

How to setup modelsim such, that PSL asserts stop the simulation?

Comment: Try running that specific test stand-alone, i.e. outside of the VUnit framework. You might find it works as intended. If so, you have a VUnit interaction (e.g. VUnit rewrites the simulation options for its own purposes) which is best solved on VUnit's gitter chat. I've found them very helpful and responsive.

Comment: This is what I indeed did. And modelsim just refuses to stop when PSL is asserted. Even weirder, modelsim this assert shows in blue-color as if it was just a warning, but it is indeed prefixed with '**Error'. When an ordinary assert happens, it is displayed in red color and simulation stops immediatelly. And it seems that `assertion fail` command has absolutely no influence on behaviour of modelsim.

Comment: **UPDATE** It seems, that `assertion fail` command works only on a specific assert. Hence if required: `assertion action -cond fail -exec break /adc_minmax_tb/DUT/assert__0`, this will indeed break execution when this specific assert happens, but it will not do anything with other asserts.

Comment: Consider evaluating function `ended` and invoking std.env.stop. (10.4c SE User Guide, Verification with Assertions and Cover Directives Using PSL Assertions and Cover Directives).

Answer (score 0):

This post is a bit old, but you can ask to modelsim/questa to break on any PSL assertion with following tcl command:

`assertion fail -r / -action break`